# How to set request body params in karate for soap request

Tags: karate

Till now i had work related to rest API only but now there is some new working coming for soap service
i want to know do we have something in karate for setting request body params same as we do for json

```
Given url 'www.example.com'
And headers {}


And xml xmlData = read('classpath:features/test.xml')

Then set xmlData.data1 = 'x'
And set xmlData.data2 = 'y'

Then request xmlData
Then method POST
Then status 200
```

I want to set xmlData as above.

Comment: I know this comment may be a waste of my time, but do try to read the docs ! https://github.com/intuit/karate#soap-action

Comment: sure peter, i got through the docs my problem is in xml we all know that we have params different for soap like below 
<cap:data><acc:detail> etc
now this colon is creating problem while doing xmlData /cap:data

Comment: Thanks a lot peter , actually while processing it works what i was trying to do is printing that statement as below 
* print xmlData /cap:data
It may not print but while printing the xml again after setting it works :)

Comment: it is working for me (I'm being as vague as your comment)